# Old DNS Domain Name / Suffix

Tags: dns

I received a PC from work - completely wiped clean and formatted. However, when I look through the network and sharing centre, I can see that the DNS Domain Name / Suffix is still showing as an old name. How do I get rid or change it? I was advised about DNS Flush, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it still connected to the old work network?

If so, this is coming from the DHCP server. It will very depending on what network you're connected to. Otherwise, the machine hasn't really been wiped.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response - it's not connected to work anymore, I have it at home. I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I bought windows 10 and installed it on a new SSD I bought. The original HDD is just there for additional storage. Where would the DNS info be stored - can I get rid of it without wiping the PC again and reinstalling windows etc

Comment: It sounds like you've not actually booted the new SSD and it's booted the old one then.

Answer (score 0):

Press win + pause or copy this into your Explorer:
Systemsteuerung\System und Sicherheit\System

And look at the setting in my screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of the settings]

If there is still your work domain the laptop didn't get wipe.
Then just leave the Work Domain and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I may just leave it, can't be bothered wiping it again and having to install everything again. If it isn't going to affect anything, then I'm not worried. It's just annoying when I connect something to the PC, it comes up with someone else's name